# passing variables from PHP FORM to JAVASCRIPT and update DB with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I would like to pass the variables from my php form to javascript:

The php form is in the same file as the javascript code:

```
// Version2
<?php //echo "<form method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"return addCommentsToDB(starttime,endtime,text,cat)();\" action=". $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']." >"; ?>

<form method="post" onsubmit="addCommentsToDB()" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" >

        <table width="150px" border="1" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="25px"><p>start</p></td>
            <td width="25px"><p>end</p></td>
            <td width="75px"><p>Text</p></td>
            <td width="10px"><p>cat</p></td>
            <td width="5px"><p>+</p></td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input style="width: 75px" type="time" name="starttime" id="starttime"></td>
            <td><input style="width: 75px" type="time" name="endtime" id="endtime"></td>
            <td><input style="width: 75px" type="text" name="text" id="text"><input type="hidden" id="VideoId" name="VideoId" value="<?php echo $video_id; ?>"></td>
            <td>
              <select width="15" name="cat" id="cat">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
              </select></td>
            <td><input name="ADD"  type="submit" value="add">  </td>
            </tr>

        </table>        </form>
```

The addcomments function:

function addCommentsToDB () {

```
var starttime = document.getElementById('starttime');
var endtime = document.getElementById('endtime');
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var cat = document.getElementById('cat');
alert ("starttime ="+starttime);
$.ajax({
  url: "addCommentsToDB.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {starttime: starttime, endtime: endtime, text: text, cat: cat},
        });
 request.done(function( msg ) {
      $( "#log" ).html( msg );
      $("#div2").load('loadTable.php', 
        {    'videoId': '<?php// echo $video_id ?>'
           } );
      $("#div3").load('multiTimeline.php', 
        {    'videoId': '<?php// echo $video_id ?>'
           } );
});
        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) { 
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        }); 
};
```

When I test with alert if the variables are passed I get

Alert: 
Starttime =[object HTMLInputElement]

I also tried that code to receive the variables ( with form header Version 2):

```
function addCommentsToDB (starttime, endtime, text, cat) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "addCommentsToDB.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {starttime: starttime, endtime: endtime, text: text, cat: cat},
            });
     request.done(function( msg ) {
          $( "#log" ).html( msg );
          $("#div2").load('loadTable.php', 
            {    'videoId': '<?php// echo $video_id ?>'
               } );
          $("#div3").load('multiTimeline.php', 
            {    'videoId': '<?php// echo $video_id ?>'
               } );
    });
            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) { 
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            }); 
    };
```

Comment: Replace `alert ("starttime ="+starttime);` with `alert ("starttime ="+starttime.value);`

Comment: The `document.getElementById('starttime')` line returns the input element, you then need to get the value of the field by retrieving its `value` property

Comment: `.value` append this in your vars at the top.

Comment: var starttime = document.getElementById('starttime').value;   - worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code :

```
var starttime = document.getElementById('starttime').value;
var endtime = document.getElementById('endtime').value;
var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
var cat = document.getElementById('cat').value;
```

OR

```
var starttime = $('#starttime').val();
var endtime = $('#endtime').val();
var text = $('#text').val();
var cat = $('#cat').va();
```

This might be useful for you.

Thanks!

Comment: thank you very much. Your code above works passing the variables to the javascript and using " alert ("starttime ="+starttime+"; Endtime = "+endtime+"; text = "+text); "    I get the correct variables printed out.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to pass across DOM elements to your PHP script. When this gets converted to a JSON string, an object is written as `[object HTMLInputElement]`. What you should instead so is pass the value of the element. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "addCommentsToDB.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        starttime: $('#starttime').val(), 
        endtime: $('#endtime').val(), 
        text: $('#text').val(), 
        cat: $('#cat').val()
    }
})
```

Note that I converted your `getElementById` usages to jQuery selectors for simplicity.

Comment: The array keys should also be in quotes:
`'starttime': $('#starttime').val(),` etc

Comment: @LlamaGoingNorth they don't have to be, that's down to preference.

Comment: Fair enough, it makes it easier to see your variable names in my opinion, especially when looking back at the code

Answer (score 0):

You can assing an ID/class to form and serialize() it