# after posting multiple variables sucess or request.done not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

[That post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378332/passing-variables-from-php-form-to-javascript-and-update-db-with-jquery) helped me to pass variables from a php Form to javascript.

Now I would like to send them to a php file which should update a DB with the values. For simplicity I created this file which should just return the values to check if it works:
 addCOmmentsToDBtest.php:

```
<?php
$video_id = $_POST['VideoId'];
$starttime = $_POST['starttime'];           
 echo "Test! \n StartTime = " .$starttime. " videoId = " .$video_id; ?>
```

The whole jquery $.ajax function which calls addCOmmentsToDBtest.php  is in the file below (JqueryTest.php). I tired to pass the data in the url:

```
 url: "addCommentsToDBtest.php?starttime="+ starttime +"endtime="+ endtime +"&text="+text+"&videoid="+videoid,
```

or to pass the data like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: "addCommentsToDBtest.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    'videoId': '<?php echo $video_id ?>',
    'starttime': starttime, 
    'endtime': endtime,
    'text': text, 
    'cat': cat            
      }
```

Both didn't work. The problem is also that in this simple example the string from addCOmmentsToDBtest.php

```
 echo "Test! \n StartTime = " .$starttime. " videoId = " .$video_id;
```

is not passed to the div tag "log". (I also tried  to insert the value in the db, like it should be at the end - didn't work).

To pass the string I tried:

```
   success: function(data) {
        $("#log").html("Sucess"+ data);
    }
```

or

```
  complete: function(data) {
            $("#log").html("Sucess"+ data);
        }
```

or

```
 request.done(function( msg ) {
   $( "#log" ).html("Sucess! Msg =" + msg );
});
```

The screenshot of the Chrome debugger:

[image]

The question is: How can I pass the Data from addCOmmentsToDBtest.php back to check if the variables got transfered in this simple example?

And what I try to achieve in the end is: 
To pass the Data from JqueryTest.php to addCOmmentsToDBtest.php and update my DB.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here the file which contains the whole javascript and php form.

JqueryTest.php:

```
<?php
 $video_id = '153fb143';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>JQUERY</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>

function addCommentsToDB () {
    var videoid = document.getElementById('videoid').value;
    var starttime = document.getElementById('starttime').value;
    var endtime = document.getElementById('endtime').value;
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    var cat = document.getElementById('cat').value;

    alert ("starttime ="+starttime+"; Endtime = "+endtime+"; text = "+text);

    $.ajax({
      url: "addCommentsToDBtest.php?starttime="+ starttime +"endtime="+ endtime +"&text="+text+"&videoid="+videoid,     
//  check ''
//  url: "addCommentsToDBtest.php?starttime="+ starttime +"endtime="+ endtime +"&text="+text+"videoId='"+videoId+"'",

// with data use that:
//  url: "addCommentsToDBtest.php",
      type: "POST",
/*  Does not Work  
    data: {
        'starttime': starttime, 
        'endtime': endtime,
        'text': text, 
        'cat': cat },     */

       success: function(data) {
            $("#log").html("Sucess"+ data);
        }
    });

    };

</script>

</head>
<body> 

<div id="log"> <p>log</p></div>
<div id="msg"></div>


<table>
<tr>
<td><div id="div1">div1</div></td>
<td><div id="div2">div2</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="div3">div3</div></td>
<td><div id="div4">
<!--ADD Table-->

<form method="post" onsubmit="addCommentsToDB()" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" >

        <table width="150px" border="1" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="25px"><p>start</p></td>
            <td width="25px"><p>end</p></td>
            <td width="75px"><p>Text</p></td>
            <td width="10px"><p>cat</p></td>
            <td width="5px"><p>+</p></td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input style="width: 75px" type="time" name="starttime" id="starttime"></td>
            <td><input style="width: 75px" type="time" name="endtime" id="endtime"></td>
            <td><input style="width: 75px" type="text" name="text" id="text"><input type="hidden" id="VideoId" name="VideoId" value="<?php echo $video_id; ?>"></td>
            <td>
              <select width="15" name="cat" id="cat">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
              </select></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="videoid" id="videoid" value="<?php echo $video_id ?>"><input name="ADD"  type="submit" value="add">  </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        </form>

</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing with trailing slash in url part `url: "/addCommentsToDBtest.php"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all set `addCommentsToDB(); return false;` into onsubmit of your form. Without it your form will continue submitting.
Second don't use url with GET parameters if you are using ajax POST. Send your data using `data` attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!  it works perfectly when I send the variables in the URL and access them with get.  It also works when I send them using data and type: "GET".

Comment: What I don't understand is: In other cases I tried to send the data to the php file using:   type: "POST" and I put my variables into data: like data: {'endtime': endtime}   but I couldn't access them using _POST in the php file. Is it only possible to send the data using GET ?

Comment: You can't access to them because you didn't used `return false;` in your form tag. Without it browser first called your ajax method in the background and then submits the whole form in standard way. Thats why you didn't saw any data in your php script. Now if everything is set up, you can use your POST ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `&` to the 2nd variable

```
 url: "addCommentsToDBtest.php?starttime="+ starttime +"endtime="+ endtime +"&text="+text+"&videoid="+videoid,
```

Should be

```
 url: "addCommentsToDBtest.php?starttime="+ starttime +"&endtime="+ endtime +"&text="+text+"&videoid="+videoid,
```